# How to Define custom property in the same component in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to define a custom property *count*. But following gives error:*Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'p'*. How to remove this error and make *count* a custom property of `<p>`

**other.component.html**

```
<p [count] = "10">
  other works!
</p>
```

**other.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  templateUrl: './other.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other.component.css']
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() count = 10;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: what is expected result in html?

Comment: @Maximus I am expecting it to run normally without errors. Just it.

Answer (score 12):

`<p>` doesn't have a `name` property. 
You can bind to the `name` attribute using

```
[attr.name]="name"
```

or alternatively

```
attr.name="{{name}}"
```

Use this 2nd form (interpolation) only for binding string values, because the passed value will always be stringified.

Comment: Thanks. As per your previous answer, I have change created other component and tried creating custom property in it. But it still giving the same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: This would need `selector: 'p'` instead of `selector: 'app-other'` for `<p [count]="10"`>other works!</p>` to become an `OtherComponent` where you can pass `count`, or you change `<p...` to `<app-other [count]="10"`>other works!</app-other>`

Comment: Could you please explain. why? Any reference?

Comment: Because the selector has to match an element, otherwise Angular wouldn't know where to create a component. See the tutorials in https://angular.io. That's one of the most basic things in Angular.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm: We can pass the variables of component class only in <selector>. And not in any other HTML tag. RIght?

Comment: By making a plain HTML element an Angular component, it gets the components (or directives) capabilities added. The element basically becomes the component. Otherwise it will just stay a plain HTML element which only has the standard properties (`<p>` doesn't have `name` or `count`). For an element to become a component, the selector needs to match. Angular searches the template for HTML that matches component or directive selectors and when found upgrades them to components.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `@Input()` decorator here, as we are communicating within the same `Component`?

Comment: I think the intentiin was to pass `count` from the parent component. The literal value in the binding was probably just a simplification to locate the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in using @Input of Angular.

@Input() count = 10 -> it is used to set property for your component which named that 'app-other'. So you must set count property at parent component.

For example in app.component.html:

```
<div>
   <app-other [count] = 10></app-other>
</div>
```

Hope that help!